# How to resolve FCM curl failed error?

Tags: android

I have implemented push notification using Fire base Cloud Messaging in Android, before today its working fine. But now, its not working.

It shows Error like this:

> Curl failed: Failed to connect to fcm.googleapis.com port 443:
>   Connection timed out

```
<?php 

function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
         'data' => $message
        );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = API KEY ',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);           
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}



$tokens = "Token here..";

$message = array("message" => " FCM PUSH NOTIFICATION TEST MESSAGE");
$message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
echo $message_status;



?>
```

Now How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, that the port no. 443 was blocked on the server for some reason. now its working fine.
Thank you